Can I use PVC planks for a fence?
I'm planning to make a white slatted fence, similar to the image below, but in white. I plan to use white-painted posts and galvanized finishing nails. Would it be crazy, or even bad in any way to use PVC trim boards (like these 1"x3" PVC Slats.) In some ways, they are perfect: no warping or chipping paint. Is there anything I'm overlooking?


As long as they are for outside, there should not be a problem with using them, besides the wind/stuff banging into them. Trim boards are usually made thinking there is support behind them all the way, not posts 8 ft away.  Local(city/HOA) regulations might be another matter.

Most of the plastic fences you see in the countryside are PVC these days. However, they're usually built with tubular rails for low weight and high rigidity. The planks you referenced may be low density (almost like foam) and not up to spanning between posts without sagging over time.
Also, they tend to have a rough texture which might collect dirt and have a dingy appearance. The purpose-built fencing has a smooth, glossy finish.
If you address those concerns with your design and use case, it should be fine.

Never mind the dirt. Also bear in mind that PVC for indoor use (or the coloring pigment added to it) may be much more sensitive to UV than an outdoor variety. It may start to discolor quite quickly as well.

@Tonny the typical Azek boards you can get have UV protection, and can also be painted.

@Huesmann It may be different were you live, but here (Europe) most indoor stuff doesn't do well with outdoor levels of UV. Azek is unknown around here, but from what I see on the internet it is specifically for outdoor use (trim and siding) so it would make perfect sense to be UV resistant. I have no idea if the stuff he mentions as example is indoor or outdoor. That link points to HomeDepot which uses geo-fencing. Their websites are not accessible outside North America, so I can't take a look.

If built as in the picture your plan can work well.
It appears that the slats are anchored every 3 feet. Doing this will greatly reduce the risk of them sagging.
The issue I see is cost. If you are to make a 6 foot high fence, it would require 24 slats. That would mean slats for a single 8 foot long x 6 foot high section of fence would cost about $320.  This does not take into account the costs of posts  or nails. So a single section of fence could cost almost $400.
If the cost is not an issue for you, go for it.

Materials vary (I’ve used azek), but a 3’ span is a lot, and I’d expect any lightweight plastic to sag embarrassingly.

Thank you! I'm leaning toward using painted 2x3s after all. I'm quite worried about the sagging possibility. One follow up questions: Should I use treated wood (which I would dry out), even if I'll be painting it?

Should you use treated wood?  That depends on how long you think you will be having the fence. Untreated will rot in 5 years or less. Water will get in where the screws and nails are and it will rot. Sealing will delay a bit but it will rot anyway.  I would use treated wood and let it age for 3 months at least.
